# Jquery concatenation for time value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime, concatenation

I have time value is coming like this from the database: `00:30:00`

This my code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var gdtesttime  = <?php echo $jobDetails['gd_time']; ?>;    // 00:30:00
console.log(gdtesttime);
var a = gdtesttime.split(':');
var gdseconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 ;
```

i want to split the time in seconds and i am having this issue while saving the time in `var gdtesttime` how can i write in javascript.?

> **My Error:** SyntaxError: missing ; before statement var gdtesttime  =
>   00:30:00;

Comment: Try this : `var gdtesttime  = '<?php echo $jobDetails['gd_time']; ?>';  `

Comment: `var gdtesttime  = <?php echo json_encode($jobDetails['gd_time']); ?>;`

Comment: @tsh : why json_encode here?

Comment: @YoYo because we need the php code print a javascript literal value, that is exactly what json does.

Comment: @tsh :But here there is no array  which needs to be json encoded. $jobDetails['gd_time'] is just a value which can be used directly in js . Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you pls try this : -

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var gdtesttime  = '<?php echo $jobDetails['gd_time']; ?>';    // 00:30:00
console.log(gdtesttime);
var a = gdtesttime.split(':');
var gdseconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var gdtesttime = '<?php echo $jobDetails['gd_time']; ?>';     // 00:30:00
console.log(gdtesttime);
var a = gdtesttime.split(':');
var gdseconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 ;
```